# Integration of mendeley with libre

Tags: libreoffice, plugins, mendeley

I am trying to integrate mendeley plugin with libre office but I get this error when ever I try to install plugin.

"Couldn't Install LibreOffice Plugin The LibreOffice unopkg utility gave the following output: ERROR: (com.sun.star.deployment.DeploymentException) { { Message = "Error binding package: vnd.sun.star.expand:$UNO_USER_PACKAGES_CACHE/uno_packages/lu1926985ayul.tmp_/Mendeley-1.19.4.oxt", Context = (com.sun.star.uno.XInterface) @564daa721340 (ImplementationName = "com.sun.star.comp.deployment.bundle.PackageRegistryBackend") }, Cause = (any) { (com.sun.star.ucb.InteractiveAugmentedIOException) { { { { Message = "an error occurred during file opening", Context = (com.sun.star.uno.XInterface) @564daa725fe8 (ImplementationName = "com.sun.star.comp.ucb.FileContent") }, Classification = (com.sun.star.task.InteractionClassification) ERROR }, Code = (com.sun.star.ucb.IOErrorCode) NOT_EXISTING }, Arguments = ([]any) { { (com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue) { Name = "Uri", Handle = (long) -1, Value = (any) { "file:///home/maddox/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/lu1926985ayul.tmp_/Mendeley-1.19.4.oxt" }, State = (com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState) DIRECT_VALUE } }, { (com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue) { Name = "ResourceName", Handle = (long) -1, Value = (any) { "/home/maddox/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/lu1926985ayul.tmp_/Mendeley-1.19.4.oxt" }, State = (com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState) DIRECT_VALUE } } } } } } ERROR: Exception occurred: Error binding package: vnd.sun.star.expand:$UNO_USER_PACKAGES_CACHE/uno_packages/lu1926985ayul.tmp_/Mendeley-1.19.4.oxt ERROR: unopkg failed"

I have both libre and mendeley in updated version.

Comment: What are your Ubuntu and LibreOffice versions? I do not have any issues installing *Mendeley-1.19.4.oxt* on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with default LibreOffice 6.0.7.3.

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 18.04.3 (bionic) . I am using libre version 6.3.4.2  30(build:2)  to be precise.

Comment: I have currently done  "rm -rf .config/libreoffice " and then I downloaded plugin from tools of Mendeley. It is working fine at the moment but I am not sure if I did the right thing. [As before this I removed and reinstalled same libre version earlier but error persisted/returned after couple of mins].

Answer (score 0):

Please install mendeley using the software store and search for the .oxt file
from terminal.
Below is from my machine

```
drsomu@DrSomuAndSons:/$ sudo find . -type f -name "*.oxt"
[sudo] password for drsomu: 
find: ‘./run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
./var/lib/flatpak/app/com.elsevier.MendeleyDesktop/x86_64/stable/2fb919344eb24d71714cf656b00ba5aa2e955a7ba12f00e2ec7afd623ec13b36/files/extra/share/mendeleydesktop/openOfficePlugin/Mendeley-1.19.8.oxt
```

Then use the extension and add the oxt file manually and it is done .... please check for https://rajaselvaraj.in/blog/mendeley-plugin-libreoffice/